# Rice wine making stucked half way, fermentation never happened?

Tags: sake

I am trying to make glutonous rice wine, purchased the so call "yeast" from asian market, the "white cookie/powder" broke rice down into sugar.

I have measured, it is 40%, very sweet to taste. But it just does not ferment. The sweetness always there, does not reduce.

I tried to pitch the champage yeast into it, it only last 2 days, before bubbles stopped.
Why?

Is it too sweet (40%) for champage yeast?

Thanks

Comment: The home brewing SE site would be better for this question.